# Find the molarity of the filtrate

Tags: solutions, stoichiometry, filtering

I can't figure out this stoichiometry question!

*10.0 mL of 1.15M copper(II) nitrate reacted with 20.0 mL of .85M ammonium hydroxide.  The solution is filtered. Determine the molarity of the filtrate.*

I figured out that the net ionic equation is Cu + 2OH -> Cu(OH)2, so the 2NH4NO3 dissolves, and the Cu(OH)2 probably doesn't pass through the filter, but I don't know where to go from there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is poorly worded since it doesn't specify for which chemical species the molarity is desired. Copper(II) would seem to be the species of interest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\ce{Cu(NO3)2}+2\ce{NH4OH} =>\ce{Cu(OH)2}(s)+2\ce{NH4NO3} $$
Essentially, we're trying to find the Molarity of $\ce{NH4NO3}$ since the copper filters out(as you stated)

First solve for limiting reagent. $$10mL\ce{Cu(NO3)2}*\frac{1L}{1000mL}*\frac{1.15mol}{1L}=0.0155mol\ce{Cu(NO3)2}$$
$$20mL\ce{NH4OH}*\frac{1L}{1000mL}*\frac{0.85mol}{1L}=0.0170mol\ce{NH4OH}*\frac{1}{2}=0.0085$$

- Why do we divide mols of $\ce{NH4OH}$ by 2? Remember that for every molecule of $\ce{Cu(NO3)2}$, there must be 2 molecules of $\ce{NH4OH}$. $$\frac{2\ce{NH4OH}}{\ce{Cu(NO3)2}}$$ for this reason we need to divide the amount of $\ce{NH4OH}$ by 2 to compensate for stoicheometry. 
  So actually, $\ce{NH4OH}$ our limiting reagent. 
  Since you didn't give my any solubility constants, I'm going to assume 100% of the Copper became  $\ce{Cu(OH)2}(s)$ and all of the ammonium became $\ce{NH4NO3}$. In the real world, perciptates never form at 100%.

0.0085 mols of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ is produced. You want $\ce{NH4NO3}$  Can you use stoichometric ratios to proceed from there? Molarity - (mol/L). Make sure you add up the two volumes to find the Total volume.

Comment: You assumption that all the copper was converted to copper hydroxide is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I know. but usually in HS chemistry when students are learning stoichometry, they generally ignore Solubility constants and whatnot. I'll edit my post a little.

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I found that .83 grams of Cu(OH)2 was produced using stoichiometry, but I don't think this would help. I don't know what to do with the Total volume of 30 mL. I also figured out that .003 moles of excess reactant remains after the reaction, so that might affect my answer. The answer key says  the answer is .10M

Comment: Whoops. That's embarrassing- looks like I didn't help much. In that case use the numbers you got.  0.003mol/30mL= .003mol/.03L . =0.10 mol/L = molarity of excess reactant in solution.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was confused about what molarity meant (since we learned about it a while ago), but now it makes sense.

Comment: :) Glad I could help, even it's just a bit. ;)

Comment: Dah... the answer is wrong. Assume all ammonia is present as species $\ce{NH4^+OH^{-}}$. So there is 0.0085 mols of $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ produced, but there is 0.155 - 0.0085 = 0.070 moles/L of Cu left in solution.

Comment: That's what I thought! Maybe there was more to the question that he didn't post.